# Cauchy differential equation $x^3\frac{\mathrm d^3y}{\mathrm dx^3}+3x^2\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}+x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=x^3\log x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$x^3\frac{\mathrm d^3y}{\mathrm dx^3}+3x^2\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}+x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=x^3\log x$$

I just want to know how to find the particular integral of $\dfrac{x^2\log x}{(D+1)^2}$.

Comment: $$C=const,\log(x)$$ and $$\log(x)^2$$ are solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that what is wanted is a particular solution of the non-homogeneous ODE.

HINT:

The simplest way is to proceed with trial and error method.

The form of the non-homogeneous term $x^3\ln(x)$ suggests to try $ y= ax^3\ln(x)$. Putting it into the ODE leads to $x^3y'''+3x^2y''+xy'=27ax^3\ln(x)+4ax^3$

So, taking $a=\frac{1}{27}$ gives the expected term. But a new term $\frac{4}{27}x^3$ is introduced. We have to annihilate it . The form $x^3$ of this term suggest to try $y=bx^3$. Putting it into the ODE leads to $x^3y'''+3x^2y''+xy'=4bx^3$

Taking $b=-\frac{1}{27}$ gives the expected value $-\frac{4}{27}x^3$. Finally, the particular solution is :

$$y=\frac{1}{27}x^3\ln(x)-\frac{1}{27}x^3$$